# DocumentDB updateOne fails with 163 Name is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I've seen issues with $ prefixed fields when writing into Mongo/Document DB, I still don't get what I'm missing.

writing into collections `sessions` works fine:

```
db.updateOne(
  { _id: '32c8529b-561f-413c-a6eb-daffbdf1b1e0_google-oauth2|666666666666666666666' },
  { '$set': { _id: '32c8529b-561f-413c-a6eb-daffbdf1b1e0_google-oauth2|666666666666666666666', value: {} } },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

however writing into collection `data` fails:

```
db.updateOne(
  { _id: 'google-oauth2|666666666666666666666' },
  { '$set': { _id: 'google-oauth2|666666666666666666666', value: { data: [Object], revision: 76 } } },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

With message: `163 MongoError Name is not valid for storage`

Both collections have been implicitly created, there's no extra config.

I can only guess at this point that the data (which is a 200kb JSON) contains some key that results in this? there's no $ signs in that whole JSON and most of the keys are uuids.

Any idea what's broken here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you add a sample document?

Comment: are there any dots in the field name?

Comment: @meet-bhagdev yeah I ended up retrieving some of the payloads in question and it turned out some used email addresses as keys – with dots. (the mongo shell error message was super helpful by the way: `E QUERY    [js] WriteError: Document can't have '.' in field names: xyz@abd.com`)

Comment: awesome! yeah, DocumentDB does not allow dots in the field names. Are you able to workaround the limitation?